# How to merge two dataframes with list entries in Pandas where only one entry of the list must match?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, nested

Trying to merge a dataframe when there are multiple values for the columns I am merging on?

I am attempting to merge two dataframes on a column that has list entries. I want the merge to occur if any of the values in the list match.  For example, I have dataframe that looks as shown below:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| a | [val1, val2, val3] |
| b | [val4, val5] |

My goal is to merge this to a dataframe on column b that looks as follows

| Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- |
| x | val1 |
| y | val4 |

The result I am looking for would be

| Column A | Column D | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | val1 | x |
| b | val4 | y |

I cannot find a way to do this using Pandas alone, and was wondering if I need to write my own function to perform this type of merge.

Comment: Looks like you want to merge with the exploded version? `df_a.explode("Column B")`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it looks like you need to do some preprocessing before merging. Essentially, you want to unlist the elements in your list and have one row per each element in the list. After this step, you should be able to use a standard `merge` operation.

Here is a rough example of how you can accomplish this in Python using pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Assuming your dataframes are df1 and df2

# Create a new dataframe where each value in the list of df1.Column B
# has its own row (with the corresponding value from df1.Column A)
df1 = df1.explode('Column B')

# Now you can merge the two dataframes
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='Column B', right_on='Column D', how='inner')

# Drop the extra columns
merged_df = merged_df.drop(['Column B', 'Column D'], axis=1)

# Rename the columns if needed
merged_df.columns = ['Column A', 'Column C', 'Column D']

# Your merged dataframe is ready
```

This code will create a new row for each element in the lists in `df1['Column B']`. Then, it merges `df1` with `df2` where the exploded `Column B` matches `Column D`. It finally cleans up the resulting DataFrame by dropping the unnecessary columns and renaming the remaining ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = df2.merge(df.explode("Column B"), right_on='Column B', left_on='Column D')
```

Answer (score 0):

example that merge two dataframes on a column that contains list entries and match any value within the lists

```py
import pandas as pd

def merge_df(df1, df2, col1, col2):
    merged_data = []
    for _, row1 in df1.iterrows():
        for _, row2 in df2.iterrows():
            if any(item in row2[col2] for item in row1[col1]):
                merged_data.append([row1['Column A'], row2[col2], row2['Column C']])
    merged = pd.DataFrame(merged_data, columns=['Column A', 'Column D', 'Column C'])
    return merged

# Example usage
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Column A': ['a', 'b'],
                    'Column B': [['val1', 'val2', 'val3'], ['val4', 'val5']]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Column C': ['x', 'y'],
                    'Column D': ['val1', 'val4']})

merged_df = merge_df(df1, df2, 'Column B', 'Column D')
print(merged_df)
#   Column A Column D Column C
# 0        a     val1        x
# 1        b     val4        y
```